# Lyapunov's theory for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use Lyapunov's theory to discuss stability of the origin for

$$x' = -x^3 - xy^2 + xy^5$$

$$y' = -y^3 + x^2y - 3x^2y^4$$

$$L(x,y) = ax^2 + by^2$$

In class, we define $L(x,y)$ as being positive definite. Then we determine if the origin is a critical point. The we take the derivative of $L$ and determine if it's a negative definite or negative semidefinite.

I can get to the point where we take the derivative. Simplifying and determining the negative definite or negative semidefinite is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Given the system

$\dot x = -x^3 - xy^2 + xy^5, \tag 1$

$\dot y = -y^3 + x^2y - 3x^2y^4, \tag 2$

it is easily seen that $(0, 0)$ is a critical point; we seek a Lyapunov function of the form

$L(x,y) = ax^2 + by^2; \tag 3$

we have

$\dot L = 2ax \dot x+ 2by \dot y$
$= 2ax(-x^3 - xy^2 + xy^5) + 2by(-y^3 + x^2y - 3x^2y^4)$
$= -2ax^4 -2ax^2y^2 + 2ax^2y^5 -2by^4 +2bx^2y^2 -6bx^2y^5$
$= -2ax^4 - 2by^4 + 2(b - a)x^2y^2 + (2a - 6b)x^2y^5; \tag 4$

we may exploit our freedom in the selection of $a$ and $b$ to ensure that

$\dot L(x, y) < 0 \tag 5$

along the trajectories of (1)-(2) in a neighborhood of the origin:  we choose

$0 < a = 3b; \tag 6$

then

$2a - 6b = 0, \tag 7$

$b - a = -2b; \tag 8$

such a choice of $a$ and $b$ eliminates the complicating term $(2a - 6b)x^2y^5$ from (4); we are left with an expression containing only even powers of $x$ and $y$, *viz*.

$\dot L = -6bx^4 - 2by^4 - 2bx^2y^2 < 0 \tag 9$

whenever at least one of $x$, $y$ does not vanish; thus

$L = 3bx^2 + by^2 \tag{10}$

is a suitable Lyapunov function for (1)-(2) in the vicinity of $(0, 0)$, and in conclude that the origin is an asymptotically stable critical point of (1)-(2).

Comment: Do you mind helping me on my other questions? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194372/poincar%C3%A9-bendixson-theorem?noredirect=1#comment6574054_3194372                                                            https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194356/test-for-the-existence-or-nonexistence-of-a-periodic-solution                                                                              https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193081/existence-of-a-periodic-solution-from-differential-equations

Comment: @Fringe_Agent13:  I'll take a look.