# Test for the existence or nonexistence of a periodic solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Discuss the existence or nonexistence of a periodic solution for the following equation. Find the region where your result holds.

$$x'' + \big(3-(x')^2\big)x' + x = 0 $$

At first glance, I thought this was the Lienard Equation until I seen the fact that the equation isn't linear. So I decided to use the Bendixon negative test first.

I started off by creating a system of equations:

\begin{align}
y &= x' \\ y' &= x''
\end{align}
After, I took the derivative of $x'$ with respect to $x$ and took the derivative of $y'$ with respect to $y$:

\begin{align}
f_x &= 0 \\ f_y &= - 3 + 3y^2
\end{align}
When adding these two together, I got

$$f_x + f_y = 0 - 3 + 3y^2$$

Here's where I'm confused.The theorem says that the sign can't change as, in this case, y changes. If I plug in 1, I get 0. If I plug in 0, I get -3. Does the 0 throw off the idea of the sign not changing? Does it count as the sign actually changing? From what I understand, 0 is neither positive nor negative. If I plug in an value greater than 1, I always get positive values. Am I on the right track with this? Does this lead to the region that I need to discuss with my answer?

I also tried the critical points idea after. For my critical point(s), I got $(0,0)$. I plugged into the Jacobian and didn't get a saddle point so we can't comment on the existence or nonexistence of a periodic solution here either.

I do know of a couple of tests that tests for the existence of a periodic solution. One of them is the Pioncare-Brendixson theorem. I'm not sure how to use it though.

Here's the theorem I was given:

> Let $R$ be an invariant region for a plane autonomous system and suppose that R has no critical point on the boundary. Then
>
> 1. If $R$ is a simply connected region that has a single unstable node or unstable spiral point in it's interior, then there's at least one periodic solution in $R$.
> 2. If $R$ is an annular region that contains no critical point of the system, then there is at least one periodic solution in $R$."

How do you use this theorem? Also, how do I find the region where my result holds? I have no idea on how to do that.

Comment: It's $-3 + 3y^2$, not $-3-3y^2$

Comment: Ok I can fix that easily. Any comment on the bigger issue?

Comment: Any help from anyone? I feel I'm on the right track but I'm not sure on how to complete this.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. The question becomes "How do I find the invariant regions of this system?"

Comment: I'm going to be 100% honest with you, I have no idea how to do that. My professor pretty threw us out here with a few questions with little explanation.

Comment: Cans someone walk me through this question please? I'm running out of time.....

Comment: So no one knows how to do this....

Comment: Can someone please help me...

Comment: If anyone is reading this and wants to help, I plotted the nullclines: y=0, y=sqrt(x+3), and y=x. The critical point is (0,0) so I can't use the Pioncare-Bendixon theory. I did notice that as long as y is greater than one, the sign won't change. The equation doesn't include x so do I assume x=0 and my invariant region will be any y value with x=0 at all times?

Answer (score 1):

Using online resources like Wolfram Alpha allows an easy way to produce a phase portrait plot

```
streamplot[{y,-x-y*(3-y^2)}, {x,-6,6}, {y,-6,6}]
streamplot[{y,-x-y*(3-y^2)}, {x,-3.3,3.3}, {y,-2.2,2.2}]
```

[image]
[image]

which clearly has signs of an instable limit cycle.

Taking the derivative of the equation and replacing $y=x'$ leads to
$$
y''+3(1-y^2)y'+y=0
$$
which is the equation of the Van der Pol oscillator which is known to have a limit cycle. This is proven using the framework of fast-slow or Lienard systems.