# Discuss the existence or nonexistence of a periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving a question where I need to discuss the existence or nonexistence of a periodic soltuion and find the region in the plane where my results holds.

$$x'' + \Bigr(3-(x')^2\Bigr)x' + x = 0$$

I took the partial derivative of both functions, added them, and the result is $3 + 3y^2$. The question is, does the function change sign as $y$ changes?

This is not the same question because I have reached a point in the question where I have a very specific separate question. I feel like I am missing something at this point which could be the solution to this problem.

Comment: It is but I didn't receive the help I needed. He simply told me of the typo rather than giving me a solution to problem.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. If you read the entire question, I have a very specific question that differs from the first post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for the existence or nonexistence of a periodic solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194356/test-for-the-existence-or-nonexistence-of-a-periodic-solution)