# Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It can be shown that $D = \{(u,v): u \geq 1/16, 0 \leq v \leq 128, u+v\leq 130\}$ is an invariant region for a system of differential equations based on a trimolecular reaction model

$$u' = (1/8) - u + u^2(v)$$

$$v' = (1/2) -u^2(v)$$

Use the Poincaré-Bendixson theory (negative or positive test) to determine if the system has a periodic solution.

I do know of the positive Poincaré-Bendixson test: Let $R$ be an invariant region for a plane autonomous system and suppose that R has no critical point on the boundary. Then

1. If $R$ is a simply connected region that has a single unstable node or unstable spiral point in it's interior, then there's at least one periodic solution in $R$.
2. If $R$ is an annular region that contains no critical point of the system, then there is at least one periodic solution in $R$.

How do you apply this to the problem? Is the domain $R$ in this case?
Do I find the critical points and see it fits into the domain?

I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Suppose we already know that $D$ is a positively invariant region.  $D$ seems to be a quadrilateral, so 2. is excluded.  So, find an equilibrium inside $D$ and check if the eigenvalues of the linearization at that equilibrium have positive real parts.

Comment: I found the critical point, which only contains u and v. I then found the Jacobian matrix and substituted that critical point. I then found the characteristic equation and plugged into the quadratic formula, where a = 1, b = (1 - 2uv - u^2), c = (u^2). Is there a more efficient way of finding the equilibrium inside the interior rather than simply substituting random numbers, hoping I land inside?

Comment: Regarding an equilibrium: from $v'=0$ you have $u^2v=1/2$, and substitute it to $u'=0$ to get $u=5/8$.  So $v=32/25$.

Comment: I took this saddle point and plugged into the Jacobian. I got a saddle point.

Comment: I went back and made a correction. I actually got an unstable spiral after substituting into the Jacobian and then using the quadratic formula.